# AppFabric Error when disable Security for sessionState Provider

Tags: asp.net, session-state, appfabric

I'm completely stuck with this version 1.0.0.0 product.

I'm running in a domain environment but for the specific application i'm using I want to disable security to reduce the workload on the servers when accessing the cache.

I've got a bunch of web servers with an existing application using SQL sessions state, and the idea was to roll out AppFabric and use the session state provider and a fast solution to speed things up. Currently have a single separate server running appFabric Host.

All Servers are on the same domain.

I've got AppFabric Running using this mode on the host

Set-CacheClusterSecurity -ProtectionLevel EncryptAndSign -SecurityMode Transport

Local App Pool on the web servers is using NETWORK SERVICE account, and i've grantedthe machine accounts permissions and it all works fine.

But then on the server i set this

Set-CacheClusterSecurity -ProtectionLevel None -SecurityMode None

(Stopping and Starting the cluster).

Then after that I get this error.

ErrorCode:SubStatus:There is a temporary failure. Please retry later. (One or more specified Cache servers are unavailable, which could be caused by busy network or servers. Ensure that security permission has been granted for this client account on the cluster and that the AppFabric Caching Service is allowed through the firewall on all cache hosts. Retry later.)

My assumption is that the client (session state provider), is set by default to use security and need to be set not too, but can't find any doco on how to change this, or i could be barking up the wrong tree.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Joel

Answer (score 5):

You can configure the client security setup in your web.config by adding a securityProperties element under the dataCacheClient element e.g.

```
<dataCacheClient>
    <hosts>
        ...
    </hosts>

    <securityProperties mode="None" protectionLevel="None" />
</dataCacheClient>
```

There's a complete reference for the client configuration settings [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790816.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for this. This actually saved me a lot of time.